# How to preserve type when plucking from object, but account for undefined keys?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Consider the below code, the code `const foundKey = classDict[key]` should have the type `object | undefined`, because it's possible to enter in a key that's not part of the `dict` object (e.g. `dict['bar']`).

However, I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this. Does anybody how to accomplish this?

## Function

```
function classMatcher<
  K extends keyof T,
  T extends baseClassDict_T
>(keys: K[], classDict: T): T[K] | undefined {
  for (let key of keys) {
    const foundKey = classDict[key]; // <---- Type = object, should equal object | undefined
    if (foundKey !== undefined) return foundKey;
  }
  return undefined;
}

type baseClassDict_T = {
  [key: string]: {
    component: (prop: any) => JSX.Element;
  };
};
```

## Usage

```
const keys = ['foo', 'bar'];
const dict = {
    foo: {
        component: //misc...
    }
}
classMatcher(keys, dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you've missed the point here. If everything is typed properly, there would be no possibility that it will evaluate to `undefined`. Let me explain.

From this type:

```
type baseClassDict_T = {
  [key: string]: {
    component: (props: any) => JSX.Element;
  }
}
```

All `key` of an object of this type will always be a string.

Next, the important part:

```
function classMatcher<K extends keyof T, T extends baseClassDict_T>(keys: K[], classDict: T)
```

The generic `K extends keyof T` basically says that K will always be a string, and this string *will always be one of the properties from T*.

What this means is that the argument `keys` can never accept any strings that is not a property of argument `classDIct`. Meaning this code:

```
classMatcher(['a', 'b', 'c'], {
  a: { component: <></> },
  c: { component: <></> }
});
```

Will always have a typing error and never get past type checking because the key "b" is not present in classDict object.

Therefore, the line:

```
const foundKey = classDict[key];
```

Will never evaluate to undefined.

See [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgY2FAvFA3gKClA2gawhAC4oBnYAJzgDsBzAXVIEMaQBuTAX00wDMArjSRwA9jSgBbZsAQALADwBpKBAAewCDQAmZKIRCi+UACoAaU6o1bdsRMAB8ACgNlSS3AwsIANszJk8EikJgCUIbhKDFAAPlBC2hB8tBDaGNhQfKKUUE4I4hT6RFBGRSBkoVg4OHDGeX4BQcAERAyVGdVQlBDAApQSvv6B9i0gDJydPDhTXT19EglJKdqcPJjSsnJOuADkzDsWOwBGB1A7CDte6TjMpDsHGUd3O9yh7EA) for the explanation in action.

Comment: I realize that the above code is stating that the key will always be in the object. I'm wondering how do I indicate in Typescript the the key might not be in the object (and therefore have a return type of `object | undefined`)

Comment: @user1543574 that's easy, just do either `const foundKey = classDict[key] as T[K] | undefined` or `const foundKey: T[K] | undefined = classDict[key]`. But why do you want to do this at all?